# Question about statement of Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is a question on the statement of Fubini's theorem for measurable sets.

The theorem looks like this:

> Let $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \lambda = \mu \times \nu)$ be a complete measure space.  If $E \in \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$ with $\lambda(E) < \infty$, then
>
> 1. $E_{x} \in \tau$ a.e. $d\mu(x)$ (that is, $\chi_{E_{x}}(y)$ is a measurable function for almost all $x$)
> 2. The map $x \rightarrow \nu(E_{x})$ is measurable a.e. $d\mu(x)$ (i.e., the map $x \rightarrow \int \limits_{X} \chi_{E_{x}}(y) \,d\nu$ is measurable a.e. $d\mu(x)$)
> 3. $\lambda(E) = \int \limits_{X} \nu(E_{x}) \,d\mu$ (i.e., $\int \limits_{X \times Y} \chi_{E} \,d\lambda = \int \limits_{X} \left [ \int \limits_{Y} \chi_{E_{x}}(y) \,d\nu \right ] \,d\mu$ -- the integral is iterated)

My questions are:

1. Since $E_{x}$ is only a measurable set for almost all $x$, then the map $\nu(E_{x})$ only exists for almost all $x$.  Then, in 2, are we showing that this map $\nu(E_{x})$ which exists almost everywhere equals a measurable function almost everywhere?
2. In statement 3, when we integrate $\nu(E_{x})$, do we really mean we are integrating the measurable function equal to $\nu(E_{x})$ almost everywhere?

I know by the time one is at an advanced level, these questions don't seem necessary, but they are absolutely necessary for me at my level.  **I really dislike talking about the integral of a non-measurable function, even though the function equals a measurable one almost everywhere.**  If you have advice on this, too, in addition to answers to my questions, I'd love to hear it.

> > > **Edit:** Is it wrong to make the following changes to the theorem statement?: For 2, we would say "the map $x \rightarrow \nu(E_{x})$ equals a measurable function $\hat{f}$ almost everywhere $d\mu(x)$.  Then, for 3, we would say $\lambda(E) = \int \limits_{X} \hat{f} \,d\mu$, rather than writing it as the integral of a function that isn't necessarily defined everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation in 1 and 2 is correct. Regarding the point

> I really dislike talking about the integral of a non-measurable function, even though the function equals a measurable one almost everywhere.

I share your dislike. This is why I think that spaces $X$ and $Y$ should themselves be assumed complete. On a complete measure space, a function that is a.e. equal to a measurable function is itself measurable.

It's true that $\nu(E_x)$ is only defined almost everywhere: for some values of $x$, the set $E_x$ may be nonmeasurable. So, at some point (preferably, before Fubini's theorem) it should be said that on a complete measure space $(X,\mu)$, we can interpret $\int_X f\,d\mu$ even if $f$ is only defined on some set $A\subset X$ such that $\mu(X\setminus A)=0$. Namely, we interpret $\int_X f\,d\mu$ as $\int_X f\chi_A\,d\mu$, setting the function to be $0$ on the complement of $A$. Or any other number, does not matter.

In a complete measure space, negligible sets can be safely neglected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough response.  What you said helped me a lot.  But I still have some issues that are disturbing me.  The main issue is: suppose, as you said, the measure space is complete and $f$ is defined only almost everywhere (suppose only for $x \not \in N$ with $\mu(N) = 0$).  Now, you said we can define $\int \limits_{X} f \,d\mu$ as $\int \limits_{X} f\chi_{X\setminus N} \,d\mu$.  But I strongly feel like this isn't rigorous.  Why? Because I am unsure if this integral equals the integral $\int \limits_{X} f \,d\mu$ with the measure space $X \setminus N$...

Comment: (and the $\sigma$-algebra induced by $X\setminus N$) -- that is, the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma^{*} = \{ E \mid E = A \setminus N,\, A \in \Sigma \}$.  The measure should be the same as the original measure.  How does one check that the integral under this $\sigma$-algebra equals the integral with respect to $f$ under the original $\sigma$-algebra?  I hope this question makes sense.  I feel like it is very important for the integrals to be equal, but I don't know that they are.

Comment: @user46944 They are equal, because the integral of any function over a set of measure zero is zero. (Integral is a limit of integrals of certain simple functions; on a set of measure  zero, all of those integrate to zero).

Comment: So basically you are saying that if $f$ is only defined on $X\setminus N$ with $\mu(N) = 0$, then $\int \limits_{X \setminus N} f \,d\mu$ (defined as $\sup \limits_{s \text{ simple}} \{ \int \limits_{X \setminus N} s \,d\mu \mid 0 \leq s \leq f \}$ (note that these simple functions are only defined on $X \setminus N$), is equal to the integral of the integral of the "extension" $\int \limits_{X} \hat{f}(x) \,d\mu$, where $\hat{f}(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \not \in N \\ 0 & x \in N \end{cases}$.

Comment: @user46944 Yes. And the reason is that from any simple function on $X$ we chap chop off the bits that are in $N$, getting a simple function in $X\setminus N$. Another, simpler, reason is that integrals are additive: $\int_X = \int_{X\setminus N}+\int_N$. And $\int_N=0$ because the measure, when restricted to $N$, is identically zero.